# Documentation for creating a gdb server

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver, openocd

I am working on building a processor, as a pasttime project. The thing is going to have a Mips isa and will probably use uart to communicate with the host machine.

Let us say that I actually get to a somewhat working CPU, then I want to run GDB to debug the code (and the CPU, probably). I have worked with embedded processors and used programs such as OpenOCD and JLink, both of which provide a tcp port to connect GDB to and then you can start debugging.

What would be ways for me to implement such a gdb server for my (or any) new platform? Extending OpenOCD? Is there documentation about what GDB expects when connecting to a remote target?

Comment: https://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean4/embecosm-howto-rsp-server-ean4-issue-2.html